# anomaly detection for payment industry's 3 dimension data

Tags: time-series, outliers, anomaly-detection

Assuming there is a time series dataset of 3 columns: userid, timestamp, transaction_amount. There are millions of users. Years of data. What might be an easy and fast algo/ models to detect anomalies here?

STL seems to be able to handle 2 columns/ dimension well (for example, timestamp, transaction_amount per day), but doesn't seem to be able to handle 3 columns (userid, timestamp, transaction_amount) here together. Unless my understanding of STL is incorrect.

An unsupervised machine learning algo, Local Outlier Probabilities, seems to be a good fit here and provides good visualization.  But when the 3 dimensional dataset is huge like this, the performance seems to be a real issue.

https://github.com/vc1492a/PyNomaly

Kriegel H., Kröger P., Schubert E., Zimek A. LoOP: Local Outlier Probabilities. 18th ACM conference on Information and knowledge management, CIKM (2009)

Wonder if anyone might have any thoughts? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

userid, timestamp are not right variables to pass for local outlier probability as these are categorical. Where do u get distance for user ids?

1) First define what is abnormality for you? 'I am going to find abnormality' is incorrect problem statement. Have a clear definition of abnormality. is it just outlier so you can think of LOF or other algo.

2) sometimes just a distribution of data would help in detecting outliers.

3) you can also thing of other unsupervised algos like-

angle based outlier detection- https://machinelearningstories.blogspot.com/2018/08/anomaly-detection-in-high-dimensional.html

connectivity based outlier detection- https://machinelearningstories.blogspot.com/2018/09/connectivity-based-outlier-detection.html

going back to first point -identify abnoramlity definition first. I see only 1 variable in your data -amount. Do  you even need any algo? :P